# função nao aceita dados como parametro VS

Tags: funções, visual-studio, parâmetros

alguém poderia me ajudar?

Eu estou tentando passar os dados que o usuário insere como parâmetros em uma função de cálculo de IMC, mas a função retorna apenas "abaixo do peso". Só dá certo quando coloco os parâmetros direto quando chamo a função

O código:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Digite o seu peso: ");
var pesoUsuario = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Agora digite a sua altura: ");
var alturaUsuario = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine($"Seu diagnóstico é {retornarDiagnosticoDoUsuario(alturaUsuario, pesoUsuario)}");


string retornarDiagnosticoDoUsuario(double alturaDoUsuario, double pesoDoUsuario) //função que calcula IMC e retorna a situação do usuário

{
    double IMC = pesoDoUsuario / (Math.Pow(alturaDoUsuario, 2));
 

if (IMC < 18.5)
{
    return "abaixo do peso";
}
else if (IMC >= 18.5 && IMC <= 24.9)
{
    return "normal";
}
else if (IMC >= 25 && IMC <= 29.9)
{
    return "sobrepeso";
}
else if (IMC >= 30 && IMC <= 40)
{
    return "obesidade";
}
else
{
    return "obesidade grave";
}
```

}

Comment: e já fez debug na função para ver se os valores que está entrando estão corretos?

Answer (score -3):

Seu código tem um erro na nomeação das variáveis. Quando você captura o valor inserido pelo usuário utiliza pesoUsuario e alturaUsuario. Mas na hora de passar esses valores para a função, utiliza as nomeações peso**Do**Usuario e altura**Do**Usuario.

[image: Print da funcao]

Sendo assim, a função não reconhece valor das variáveis que você capturou do usuário.

Comment: Oii ! Obrigada pelo retorno. Eu achei que ao jogar os parâmetros pesoUsuario e alturaUsuario na função, eles se tornariam os parâmetros alturaDoUsuario e pesoDoUsuario consequentemente. Fiz a troca e deu certo, muito obrigada!